# I'm curious about Python requests.post (JSON format) and how to get a POST from a PHP server

Tags: php, json, python-3.9

python code

```
import json
import requests

temp_dict = {"user_id":"zed","user_password":"zed123","degrees":"23.5"}

r=requests.post('https://localhost:8080/php/test.php',json = temp_dict)
print(r.status_code)
```

php code

```
<?php
    echo json_decode(file_Get_contents("php://input"))->{'user_id'};
?>
```

I want to export the keys and values of the dictionary sent by Python in echo form. But I don't know how.

status_code result after running .py file: 200
text result after running .py file : null value

Comment: When you are nesting function calls like that, it's hard to pin-point where exactly things went wrong. json_decode will return null, if it was not passed valid JSON. You should check what the file_get_contents call actually returned first of all.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php

http_response_code(200);

$input = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
echo $input["user_id"];
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to the code, what you changed etc so users can learn from your changes